# Google adsense : is there a slotrenderenderevent?

Tags: adsense

I dont find anything in Google Adsense's documentation : does Adsense has adslotrendered event, like the Google Publishers tag?

Thanks !

Comment: No, there is no such event at the moment. What is your usecase for which you need it?

Comment: Thanks @MikitaBelahlazau for your answer.

I basically want to identicate if Adsense delivers me empty ads (i've seen a few recently), in order or to do something : refresh ads / add a placeholder image or something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, adsense has no features like this.
Only gpt support slotrendered event.

*** Update

Now AdSense add two tags to its ad units

Depending on whether or not an ad was returned, this parameter will update to one of the following:

data-ad-status="filled" An ad was returned to the ad unit and is now showing.

data-ad-status="unfilled"   No ads were returned and the ad unit is empty.

You can check if the ad unit is empty or not by querying data-ad-status

More info: https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/10762946?hl=en

Comment: Thanks @Niresh, I never noticed that !